# Ruby on Rails array .include? only check for reference and not object content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to assert that an array of objects contains an expected object. However even though the array indeed contains the expected object (at least from my eyes they do), the spec test kept failing and said the array does not include the object.

Here's the test:

```
bubble_dtos = [...]
expected_bubble = ...
expect(bubble_dtos).to include(expected_bubble)
```

And here's the test result:

```
Failure/Error: expect(bubble_dtos).to include(expected_bubble)
expected [<Soda::DTO::Bubble container_id=594, bubble_type="co2", flavor_id=3515, bubble_sid="soda::bubble:dbid/1413", id=1413, desc="desc1">, <Soda::DTO::Bubble container_id=594, bubble_type="co2", flavor_id=3519, bubble_sid="soda::bubble:dbid/1414", id=1414, desc="desc2">, <Soda::DTO::Bubble container_id=594, bubble_type="co2", flavor_id=3528, bubble_sid="soda::bubble:dbid/1421", id=1421, desc="desc3">] to include <Soda::DTO::Bubble container_id=594, bubble_type="co2", flavor_id=3528, bubble_sid="soda::bubble:dbid/1421", id=1421, desc="desc3">
```

Does array `.include?` only check object reference and not object content?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the docs, but it looks that it checks only object reference. How do you feel about using `include(an_object_having_attributes(...))`?

Comment: If you want to compare 2 different object with the same content, I think you can implement the equality in the object: https://www.rubyguides.com/2017/03/ruby-equality/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [ruby 2.7 docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F):

> include?(object) → true or false
>
> Returns true if the given object is present in self (that is, if any element == object), otherwise returns false.

If your `DTO` doesn't implement the equality operator `==` then it will use `Object#==` which only compares the object reference.

To add the operator to your class:

```
def ==(object)
  # handle different type
  return false unless object.is_a?(Soda::DTO::Bubble)

  # compare internal variables etc.
  object.container_id == self.container_id
end
```